# E1 or E2 Elimination? Which Elimination occurs first?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, elimination

In this reaction scheme, two dehydrobrominations occur. A bulky base is used but both hydrogens are sterically hindered. How is it possible to determine, which one is removed first? Or is this an $E_1$ elimination and the tertiary bromine leaves first?
[image: Reaction scheme]